# Airbnb DeepLinkDispatch not routing deep links

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am trying to use the Airbnb DeepLinkDispatch library in my Android application in order to handle deep links but I can't get it working.

I've created this clases:

AppDeepLinkModule.java

```
@DeepLinkModule
public class AppDeepLinkModule {
}
```

DeepLinkDispatchActivity.java

```
@DeepLinkHandler({AppDeepLinkModule.class})
public class DeepLinkDispatchActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // DeepLinkDelegate, LibraryDeepLinkModuleLoader and AppDeepLinkModuleLoader
        // are generated at compile-time.
        DeepLinkDelegate deepLinkDelegate =
                new DeepLinkDelegate(new AppDeepLinkModuleLoader());
        // Delegate the deep link handling to DeepLinkDispatch.
        // It will start the correct Activity based on the incoming Intent URI
        deepLinkDelegate.dispatchFrom(this);
        // Finish this Activity since the correct one has been just started
        finish();
    }

}
```

TestDeepLinkActivity.java

public class TestDeepLinkActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = TestDeepLinkActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@DeepLink("myapp://users")
public static Intent intentForUsers(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "." + "MY_ACTION");
    return i;
}
```

Then I've added this in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".common.DeepLinkDispatchActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
        <data android:scheme="myApp"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And when I click in a link  in a web page it is entering in the onCreate method of DeepLinkDispatchActivity but it is not dispatching the 
intentForUsers method.

Is there any thing that I missing to configure in order to make this lib working?